# Why Isn't #value valid for 'textfield' form types in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, forms

I can set `#default_value` but there is no `#value` for text fields?

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#textfield

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form API is an abstraction over regular HTML form elements, so there are cases where attributes don't match up exactly.

In the context of Form API, `#value` is for values you don't want the user changing, and doesn't make sense with respect to text `<input>` controls.

Instead, you want to use `#default_value`, which is for values you *do* want the user to change. That is:

```
$form['mytextfield'] = array(
   'type' => 'textfield',
   '#default_value' => 'Foo',
);
```

is the same as:

```
<input type="text" value="Foo" />
```

If you want to mimic the behavior of Form API's `#value` (i.e. provide a default value and prevent the user from changing it), use the `#disabled` property:

```
$form['mytextfield'] = array(
   'type' => 'textfield',
   '#default_value' => 'Foo',
   '#disabled' => TRUE,
);
```

For more information about the internals, check out [`form_builder()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_builder/7), which constructs the render array for the form and [`_form_builder_handle_input_element()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/_form_builder_handle_input_element/7), which replaces `#value` with the value of `#default_value` prior to rendering.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, that makes way more sense.  When I set the field to #disabled though, the value is always emptied in _presave.  Though closed, I'm wondering if http://drupal.org/node/687572 has crept back in.